# How to use loadMore in recyclerView in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my application i want show data from server, and from server send to me all of data. in android i should **get 10 data** and show it, when scroll and show 10 data send request to server and get other 10 data!
For server request is use `Retrofit2`.

How can i use lazy loader in android?

Comment: take a look at my project in github, https://github.com/shayanpourvatan/PaginationHandler

Answer (score 0):

Check if your API supports Limit and Offset parameters,
if it supports then request the API to give you 10 elements initially with offset 0 and then on reaching the end of list, call you service again with offset = (Number of items in list)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a page variable to web service.
Here llManager is LinearLayoutManager attached to your recycler view and total records are the total number of data available in service.

This will call your web service when you reached at last object of recycler view and your current data in recycler view is less than the total available data and increases the page count value for service to fetch new page data.

One more thing also maintains a flag isCalling to check whether a service is already running to fetch data.

```
recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int visibleThreshold = 1;
                int totalItemCount = llManager.getItemCount();
                int lastVisibleItem = llManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    if (totalRecords > totalItemCount && !isCalling) {
                        page = page + 1;

                      callwebservice();
                    }

                }

            }
        });
```